# URL masking/forwarding/redirecting

Tags: url, redirect, dns, forwarding, masking

I have a website hosted on 000webhost and a paid domain was purchased from 1and1. 1and1 offers URL redirecting with HTTP or frame redirect, but I have opted to point the paid domain to 000webhosts name servers.

Currently this works to the point that when I type the paid domain in (www.paiddomain.co.uk), it points me to the correct website (www.freedomain.com). Once on this page any page that is clicked shows up in the address bar as www.freedomain.com/link when what I want is for it to show up as www.paiddomain.com/link.

What's the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Terminology

- origin server - the server that provides the original content
- proxy server - the server that sits in the middle between the client and the origin server

In your case the origin server is freedomain.com.  It sounds like you opted out of a proxy server and just have the DNS pointing to the origin server.

### Reason

The first page loads fine because it is accessible by two domains.  However the HTML content that was delivered has absolute links to the origin server.  Therefor when the client clicks on it they are taken directly to the origin server.

### Without a proxy server you have two choices

1. Get the origin server to generate absolute links to the domain you want.
2. Get the origin server to generate relative links.

This depends on how your pages are generated (static html, drupal, wordpress, custom app).  But the net effect is that your links will be generated like this:

```
<a href="http://www.paiddomain.com/link">absolute URL</a>
```

or like this:

```
<a href="/link">relative URL</a>
```

If your site uses cookies you will also need to figure generate them for the correct domain.

For systems that generate an absolute URL they will usually have a variable that stores the "site url", "base url", or similar either in their configuration or in the database.

### With a proxy server

You can ask your proxy server to translate links (and cookies, etc) from `freedomain.com` to `paiddomain.com`.  This depends on the proxy server, in apache you would use `ProxyPassReverse`.

1and1 is apparently not willing to be your proxy server:
http://faq.1and1.com/domains/domain_admin/domain_dest/3.html
They are willing to provide a frame (poor bookmarkability), or HTTP redirect (change the URL).

Comment: Amir, I have tried using the method on the 1and1 faq. Unless there is something else i need to do, that method just keeps 'paiddomain.com' in the address bar when links are clicked instead of displaying paiddomain.com/link1 or paiddomain.com/link2.

Comment: Okay, then they aren't actually willing to be a proxy server, just providing a frame or HTTP redirect.  I think that leaves you with the "without a proxy server" options.  Editing my answer.

Comment: Amir any idea how to do this on 000webhost? Im using opencart as the backend which means the whole site is scripted in php. Appreciate your help

Comment: There is usually a way to set the URL value for what the site considers to be it's own URL.  Try system->settings->general->site url http://opencart-tutorials.com/opencart-tutorials-configuration.html  alternatively, if it's URLs are computed from PHP env variables you will need to override it.

Comment: Another path to try with opencart: http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=86595

Comment: Amir, you're an absolute star mate. I've been scratching my head, trawled the web for at least 2 hours for that answer. Are you familiar with opencart? May have a more specific question if so

Comment: @green4rrow no, not familiar with opencart, just the general principles of proxying :-)  Did that work for you then?

Comment: Perfectly. Have a look if you want - http://habitar.co.uk

Only thing that i need to clean up for SEO purposes is when you click on the logo and certain other aspects like account. The URL isn't as clean as i would like e.g. http://habitar.co.uk/index.php?route=common/home

Comment: @green4rrow cool, feel free to accept answer on this one :-)  try googling "opencart clean urls" for the SEO stuff, probably a config and set of rewrite rules

Comment: I have done bro, the version of opencart i am using (1.5.x) already has clean seo urls as an integrated feature for the majority of products, categories etc. It is just missing a little bit more that should have really been built in. All  I've have found so far are paid extensions for opencart and vqmods which are like patch xml files. I want to learn how to do it manually as it currently pulling cleaner urls from a database table with the help of a php script. I think i just need to tweak these. Will keep looking. Appreciate all your help

Answer (score 0):

With a RedirectRule in the .htaccess file:

Example - Redirect from www.freedomain.com/link to www.paiddomain.com/link:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.freedomain.com/link$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.paiddomain.com/link/$1 [L,R=301]
```

[More info](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/htaccess_redirect#newsite)

Comment: does this above method require i do this for each link on my page?

Comment: thanks but doing it at the docroot level is resulting in a google error message saying there is a redirect loop. any ideas?

Comment: This would mean each time someone clicks a link they first go to freedomain.com/link and are redirected to paiddomain.com/link.  It's going to be pretty fast so they might not notice it but still seems a bit yucky.

Answer (score 0):

I was running in to this same problem when using the frame redirect offered by 1and1.  My page had absolute URLs to an external site and when clicked they would load a blank page with my 1and1 domain in the title bar.

Chrome out put this error:

```
'absolute link to external site' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
```

Turns out when I clicked the links the browser was trying to open them in the frame 1and1 added to my page.  The solution was to add the target attribute to my links and set it to _top. This causes the links to be opened fully in the current window/tab and ignore the frame.

```
<a href="absolute link to external site" target="_top"> </a>
```